# LazyInitializationException thrown even with initializeAndUnproxy

Tags: hibernate, exception, hibernate-mapping, lazy-initialization

I need help in understanding below behavior that I observed in Hibernate. I was able to make the code work for now by adding a 'hack', so want to remove it.

Entity classes:

```
Department.java
    - Long departmentId; (Id of department) 
    - String departmentName; (Name of department)

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    - Account account; (department account)


Account.java
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name="ACCOUNTS_BATCHES")
    - Set<Long> batches;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name="ACCOUNTS_SECTIONS")
    - Set<Long> sections;


Since the fetchType is defined as Lazy, I had to do HibernateUtils.initializeAndUnproxy(), so my code is like this:

Line 1: Account account = HibernateUtils.initializeAndUnproxy((department.getAccount());

Line 2: map.put("batches", HibernateUtils.initializeAndUnproxy(account.getBatches()));       
Line 3: account.getBatches().size();

Line 4: map.put("sections", HibernateUtils.initializeAndUnproxy(account.getSections())); 
Line 5: account.getSections().size();

I only need to pass the ids of batches and sections on UI.
This works fine, but to make it work I had to explicitly add Line 3 and Line 5 (where we are doing .size())
If I remove Line 3 and Line 5, then it throws LazyInitializationException. 

My question is that why it doesn't work without adding these 2 lines and when we add it, what is happening in these 2 lines which is making it work.
Set is of type java.util.Set
```

Comment: Can you please try by changing your call to hibernate.initialize instead of HibernateUtils.initializeAndUnproxy() and see if you still need to call line 3 and 5. I have code in my app where I call the lazy loaded piece via yeh above code and I dot need .size() and I too have the same return type as yours.

Comment: Thanks @LearningPhase. I tried that as well, but same issue. I think it may be because of this line mentioned in Java docs for Hibernate.initialize():   "Note: This only ensures intialization of a proxy object or collection; it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized."   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object)